# Why are parameters to "sort block" named this way?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

My understanding was that when referencing data within an array, the counting started at zero. For example, the zeroth object in `array = ["cat", "dog", "fish"]` would be `"cat"`.

The tutorial that I am working on says to do it like this (let's say we are sorting by length of string for example).

```
array.sort {|value1,value2| value1.length <=> value2.length }
```

This *does* sort it how I want it, but my question is, if counting in array begins at "0", how come we are not doing it like this:

```
array.sort {|value0,value1| value0.length <=> value1.length }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`value1` and `value2` are just names or placeholders for each pair of values in the array. You could put another you like there:

```
array.sort {|a,b| a.length <=> b.length }
```

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up! So when I assign |A,B| does that run the comparison on each value in the array?

Comment: @JeffH.: The things in the bars are the block arguments, which are variables like any other.

Comment: @JeffH. Yeah, for each A,B in the array it sort them using the `<=>` operator. Which I believe is similar to Java's `compareTo()` method.